# Why I unable to call the function twice just in case of nested functions in PHP?

Tags: php

I have the following codes.

```
function a() {
  function b() {
    echo "I am b";
    }
  echo "I am a";
  }
```

Why I can't call a() twice, like

```
a();
a();
```

Or,

```
b();
a();
```

Both conditions return fatal error. However, calling a() first and then calling b() multiple times doesn't have any problem. Why is this so?

Comment: Is there any specific reasons why you want the "b" function nested into the "a" one ?

Comment: Please be clear about WHAT error you get. My guess is this: since `b` is declared inside `a`, calling `a` twice will result in `b` being declared twice. The second time will throw an error, because you can't have two functions with the same name. Also, `b` won't exist until `a` is called, so calling first `b` and then `a` results in an error.  Solution: don't declare functions in functions.

Comment: Just I am learning PHP. And I came across this question but couldn't find a clue. Please mention the reason for downvote. Thanking you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function b() is not really inside function a(). Your code essentially looks like this:

```
function a() {
  /* hey compiler: make a new function b() */
  echo "I am a";
}
```

In this state you cannot call function b() because it doesn't exist yet.

Once you call a() your code looks like this:

```
function a() {
  /* hey compiler: make a new function b() */
  echo "I am a";
}
function b() {
  echo "I am b";
}
```

When you call a() again it looks like this:

```
function a() {
  /* hey compiler: make a new function b() */
  echo "I am a";
}
function b() {
  echo "I am b";
}
function b() {
  echo "I am b";
}
```

And you get an error because you have two copies of function b().

Answer (score 6):

Here is what happens when you run your code PHP reads the file and defines the function `a()` but not the function `b()` because its definition is inside the function `a()`

- if you call `a()` once, then the function `b()` will be defined
- if you call `a()` twice, it will fail on the 2nd call because the function `b()` already exists and cannot be redefined
- if you call `b()` first, you will get an error because the function is not defined yet as `a()` was not called

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised this code works, but what it does it declares b() when a() is called. So b() only exists after you have called a() at least once. You cannot call a() twice, because then you would redeclare b() which isn't allowed. You could make a() work multiple times by adding a `if(!function_exists("b") { ...` around the function b();

Answer (score 2):

That's because when you call `a()`, the function `b()` is declared.

One the first run it works, but on the second run it will fail since `b()` is already declared.

You can solve it in a few ways:

### Declare `b` outside `a`

```
function a() {
  echo "I am a()";
}

function b() {
  echo "I am b()";
}
```

On this way, you will be able to call `b()` before `a()` and vice versa.

### Check if `b()` exists before declaring it

```
if (!function_exists('b')) {
  function b() {
    echo "I am b()";
  }
}
```

On this way, you will be able to call `a()` many times, but won't be able to call `b()` before `a()` be called.

### Declare `b()` as anonymous function

```
function a() {
  $b = function() {
    echo "I am the anonymous b()";
  }
}
```

The advantage (or not) of this method is that `b()` will exists only inside `a()` scope.

If you try to call `$b()` outside it, it will fail since `$b` is a local variable on `a()` scope.

Comment: this will remove the duplicate declaration error but with the last two methods you will still not be able to call `b()` before `a()`

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ of course, b() cannot be called if it was not declared.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, function `b()` is declared inside funkction `a()`, therefore is not known to the interpreter until function `a()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

well nested functions are built that way. When you define a function within another function it does not exist until the parent function is executed.
Once the parent function has been executed, the nested function is defined and as with any function, accessible from anywhere within the current document.

The reason you cant call a() twice is because repeated calls will try to redeclare the inner functions, which will generate an error.

you definitely cannot call b() before as it hasnt been defined yet.